# ActionBarSherlock with Android Action Bar Style Generator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock with Android Action Bar Style Generator (http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and it works perfectly with API v14+, but on v10-v14, I get the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.loginregistration.Login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light,     Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
        at     com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:976)
        at     com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
        at     com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:836)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
        at com.myapp.loginregistration.Login.onCreate(Login.java:25)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
```

Is there anyway to get the style generator to work with the Api 10-14? Right now I have it set to default to `Theme.Sherlock` when using the lower API phones, so the bug goes away, but its not the style I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What style would you like?

The theme generator works with stock Android Holo, ActionbarSherlock or Appcompat.

Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light and Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionbar are all just ports of Holo, Holo.Light, and Holo.Light.DarkActionbar, so any theme that you can get in api 11+, you can get with ActionbarSherlock.

What style are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Wow, I put style compatibility with Sherlock and somehow that was gone. I did it again, and seems to work fine in 10+, not 11+ as you mentioned?

Comment: I meant that holo theme was introduced in api 11 (i think). ActionbarSherlock is compatible right back to below 8 i think.